# How can I add some html to an exact position within a page?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, appendto

I am trying to figure out how to add :

```
<p id="sab-contact-tab"><a href="/contact" class="smcf-link"></a></p>
```

right after :

```
<div id="footer">
```

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var prependHTML = "<p id="sab-contact-tab"><a href="/contact" class="smcf-link"></a></p>";
    jQuery(prependHTML).prepend("#footer");
});
```

Is this code correct? if not what is the right code?

Thanks,

Michael Sablatura

Comment: The string should be contained in a single quote or the double quotes inside the string should be escaped

Comment: still not working. this is the code I am using ...

Comment: <code>jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var prependHTML = '<p id="sab-contact-tab"><a href="/contact" class="smcf-link"></a></p>';

 jQuery("#footer").prepend(prependHTML);
});</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var prependHTML = "<p id="sab-contact-tab"><a href="/contact" class="smcf-link"></a></p>";
```

Should be

```
var prependHTML = '<p id="sab-contact-tab"><a href="/contact" class="smcf-link"></a></p>';
```

or

```
var prependHTML = "<p id=\"sab-contact-tab\"><a href=\"/contact\" class=\"smcf-link\"></a></p>";
```

Comment: still not working. Would it show up in page source if viewed?

Comment: Ok I finally got it, turns out my css was not correct after I made your fix. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use simple quotes to delimiter your string (because you have some double quotes in it).

Answer (score 0):

In that situation i would always use `jQuery('#footer').append(appendHTML);` rather than `appendTo` but i don't think that would be *functionally* any different, is the code you posted not working?

Comment: Yes, the code I posted is not working. I put the code in a file named fxcntab.js and registered the script within my plugin.php file. It shows in the <head> after jquery. I'm using wordpress 3.

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var prependHTML = '<p id="sab-contact-tab"><a href="/contact" class="smcf-link"></a></p>';

 jQuery("#footer").prepend(prependHTML);
});`